# A Problem On Finite Group

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $G$ is not a $p$-group ($|G|\neq p^n$). Show that

$$ \text{Aut}(G)\ncong Q_8 $$
where $Q_8$ is quaternion group.

Comment: This is the second question of yours that shows no effort on your part. This is frowned upon. Please include in an edit any attempts you have made to solve the problem yourself before the question is closed as off topic.

Answer (score 4):

It is known that the automorphism group of a group $G$ contains a subgroup $Inn(G)$, which is called the inner automorphisms, isomorphic to $G/Z(G)$.

Assume that $G$ is a group with order divisible by at least two primes and $Aut(G)\cong Q_8$. We also know that $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup $Q_8$. But if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G/Z(G)=1$. Hence $Inn(G)=1$ or $Inn(G)=Q_8$.

Assume that $Inn(G)=Q_8$. It is easy to show that in this case $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups. Hence $Aut(G)$ is the direct product of the automorphism groups of its Sylow subgroups. But for an odd prime $p$ dividing $|G|$, the Sylow subgroup $P\in Syl_p(G)$ is element wise fixed by every automorphism of $G$ (since $P\subseteq Z(G)$). Hence $Aut(P)=1$. We know that $Aut(P)=1$ implies $|P|=1$ or $|P|=2$. Since $p$ is odd we have $P=1$, contradiction.

Now assume that $Inn(G)=1$ so $G$ is abelian. We are again in the case where $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups. But $Q_8$ cannot be written as a direct product of two nontrivial groups, i.e. every automorphism group of a Sylow subgroup of $G$ is trivial except one. Hence $|G|$ has two prime divisors, an odd prime $p$ and $2$, also Sylow $2$ subgroup of $G$ has order $2$. Let $P$ be the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Therefore $P$ is an abelian $p$-group with $Aut(P)\cong Q_8$ where $p$ is an odd prime. Since $P$ is abelian it can be written as the direct product of cyclic $p$-groups, say $P\cong C_1\times C_2\times ...\times C_r$. Now $r\neq 1$ since the automorphism group of a cyclic group is cyclic. We also know that $Aut(C_1)\times...\times Aut(C_r)$ can be embedded into $Aut(P)$. The problem is however, no subgroup of $Q_8$ can be written as a direct product. In fact, every proper subgroup of $Q_8$ is cyclic. Hence $Aut(C_i)=1$ for at least one $i$, which implies that $C_i=1$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

D. Flannery and D. MacHale proved in $1981$, in the article [Some Finite Groups Which Are Rarely Automorphism Groups I](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20489126?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) several results, e.g., the following Theorem on page $214$:

*Theorem $4$*: There is no finite group $G$ such that ${\rm Aut}(G)\cong Q_n$, where $Q_n$ is the dicyclic group of order $4n$, i.e., $Q_2$ is the quaternion group.

The proof is not difficult, and it does not seem useful to produce it here again. Actually, if $|{\rm Aut}(G)|=8$, then $G$ is isomorphic to either $D_4$ or $C_4\times C_2$, see Theorem $5$. So in any case $\text{Aut}(G)\ncong Q_8$.

Comment: I wish I saw your answer before writing mine :)

Comment: @Levent On the contrary, it is good that you wrote your answer :)